# Is there false-sharing when writing to unique elements of an output array?

Tags: multithreading, openmp, false-sharing

Is there false-sharing with `sum[]` in the following snippet of code that computes the row-wise sums of a sparse CSR matrix since independent threads update distinct locations of the array which could potentially be mapped to the same cache-line?

If yes, how can we avoid this assuming sum[] is pre-allocated and cannot be re-defined to have elements map to unique cachelines.

```
#pragma omp parallel for  
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    float row_sum = 0.;
    for (int k = rowOffsets[i]; k < rowOffsets[i+1]; k++){
      row_sum += values[k]; 
    }
    sum[i] = row_sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely a case of potential false sharing. However it's really not bad, as 1) this is just a single write at the end of each outer iteration, and 2) the default omp scheduling will group the iterations by large chunks for each thread, hence minimizing the cache line conflicts.

You could reduce further the false sharing by delaying the moment you write to `sum[]` until the end of each thread:

```
for (int i = ; i < N; i++) sum[i] = 0.f;
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    float* tmp = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    for (int i = ; i < N; i++) tmp[i] = 0.f;
    #pragma omp for  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int k = rowOffsets[i]; k < rowOffsets[i+1]; k++){
            tmp[i] += values[k]; 
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    for (int i = ; i < N; i++) sum[i] += tmp[i];
    free(tmp)
}
```

But frankly you don't need this kind of complication in the above case. It can help in some other cases, though.

Comment: Isn't the "tmp" essentially the same as using the "private" clause? Also, serializing the writes at the end seems rather inefficient. I could not find any direct references in the OMP documentation that clarifies this. As for the schedule, if I had N= number of threads available, I can't think of a way to exploit parallelism while avoiding false sharing.

Comment: Declaring `tmp` inside the parallel region is like declaring it ouside + private, but it's simpler like this. At some point you have to write to your output array, so indeed there is some potential false sharing that cannot be avoided. However, the latter usually the better. And I do not say that the above code is more efficient in *your* case, just that this approach can be more efficient in *some* cases.